# Curve fitting in Python in multi modal histogram

Tags: python, histogram, curve

I would like to find a curve which fitted to the distribution with multi modal as shown in attached image. (The image shows gaussian curve fit to the hist.) There is multi gaussian in sklearn that neads the number of modes before fitting. What if we dont know the number of modes?

[gauss curve not fit to histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xie37.png)

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach to this type of problem is to fit the data to a single gaussian, then to a double gaussian, then a triple, etc. and note when the fit statistic stops improving.

For example, the sum-of-squared errors should be less for a double gaussian than a single gaussian.  At some point the sum-of-squared error should stop improving.